# Octobercms - Disable Caching

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have created a blog using Octobercms and rainlab blogpost. When I am visiting my page, when logged in it shows me all posts but when I am logged out, it shows me 3 posts only, I checked that all the posts are published.

Please help me understand this behavior, is this a cache issue? How can I disable it or remove cache after changing in my CMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed cache problem, you can try following things:

Change the interval for cms object re-cache in `config/cms.php` (it is specified in minutes):

```
'parsedPageCacheTTL' => 1,
```

If you are in development mode and need to disable laravel cache, you can use `array` cache driver, in `config/cache.php` change:

```
'default' => 'array',
```

You can also try to run (to clear the cache):

```
./artisan cache:clear
```

My last guess would be that php `opcache` may be the root of your problems, so you can try to disable it (in `php.ini`):

```
opcache.enable=0
```

or set it to check file timestamps:
    opcache.validate_timestamps=1